# Numpy command to calculate sine (and cosine) consumes all RAM

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, trigonometry, ram

I am trying to calculate sine and cosine of month number (e.g. Jan=1, Feb=2, ... Dec=12) for a series of observations that covers ~5 years:

```
def get_sin(value, max_value):
    sine =  np.sin(value * (2.*np.pi/max_value))
    return sine

def get_cosine(value, max_value):
    cosine = np.cos(value * (2.*np.pi/max_value))
    return cosine
```

I run the following command on the data:

```
df_ufvdate['month_sine'] = df_ufvdate.apply(lambda row: get_sin(month, 12), axis=1)
```

However my desktop RAM is exausted, and then I get the following MemoryError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [466], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df_ufvdate['month_sine'] = df_ufvdate.apply(lambda row: get_sin(month, 12), axis=1)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:8839, in DataFrame.apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwargs)
   8828 from pandas.core.apply import frame_apply
   8830 op = frame_apply(
   8831     self,
   8832     func=func,
   (...)
   8837     kwargs=kwargs,
   8838 )
-> 8839 return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:727, in FrameApply.apply(self)
    724 elif self.raw:
    725     return self.apply_raw()
--> 727 return self.apply_standard()

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:854, in FrameApply.apply_standard(self)
    851 results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    853 # wrap results
--> 854 return self.wrap_results(results, res_index)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:880, in FrameApply.wrap_results(self, results, res_index)
    878 # see if we can infer the results
    879 if len(results) > 0 and 0 in results and is_sequence(results[0]):
--> 880     return self.wrap_results_for_axis(results, res_index)
    882 # dict of scalars
    883 
    884 # the default dtype of an empty Series will be `object`, but this
    885 # code can be hit by df.mean() where the result should have dtype
    886 # float64 even if it's an empty Series.
    887 constructor_sliced = self.obj._constructor_sliced

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1027, in FrameColumnApply.wrap_results_for_axis(self, results, res_index)
   1023     result.index = res_index
   1025 # we may want to infer results
   1026 else:
-> 1027     result = self.infer_to_same_shape(results, res_index)
   1029 return result

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1033, in FrameColumnApply.infer_to_same_shape(self, results, res_index)
   1031 def infer_to_same_shape(self, results: ResType, res_index: Index) -> DataFrame:
   1032     """infer the results to the same shape as the input object"""
-> 1033     result = self.obj._constructor(data=results)
   1034     result = result.T
   1036     # set the index

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:636, in DataFrame.__init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    630     mgr = self._init_mgr(
    631         data, axes={"index": index, "columns": columns}, dtype=dtype, copy=copy
    632     )
    634 elif isinstance(data, dict):
    635     # GH#38939 de facto copy defaults to False only in non-dict cases
--> 636     mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
    637 elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    638     import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py:494, in dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype, typ, copy)
    487     arrays = [
    488         arr if not is_datetime64tz_dtype(arr) else arr.copy() for arr in arrays
    489     ]
    491 if copy:
    492     # arrays_to_mgr (via form_blocks) won't make copies for EAs
    493     # dtype attr check to exclude EADtype-castable strs
--> 494     arrays = [
    495         x
    496         if not hasattr(x, "dtype") or not isinstance(x.dtype, ExtensionDtype)
    497         else x.copy()
    498         for x in arrays
    499     ]
    500     # TODO: can we get rid of the dt64tz special case above?
    502 return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py:497, in <listcomp>(.0)
    487     arrays = [
    488         arr if not is_datetime64tz_dtype(arr) else arr.copy() for arr in arrays
    489     ]
    491 if copy:
    492     # arrays_to_mgr (via form_blocks) won't make copies for EAs
    493     # dtype attr check to exclude EADtype-castable strs
    494     arrays = [
    495         x
    496         if not hasattr(x, "dtype") or not isinstance(x.dtype, ExtensionDtype)
--> 497         else x.copy()
    498         for x in arrays
    499     ]
    500     # TODO: can we get rid of the dt64tz special case above?
    502 return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:6032, in NDFrame.copy(self, deep)
   5926 @final
   5927 def copy(self: NDFrameT, deep: bool_t = True) -> NDFrameT:
   5928     """
   5929     Make a copy of this object's indices and data.
   5930 
   (...)
   6030     dtype: object
   6031     """
-> 6032     data = self._mgr.copy(deep=deep)
   6033     self._clear_item_cache()
   6034     return self._constructor(data).__finalize__(self, method="copy")

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:603, in BaseBlockManager.copy(self, deep)
    600 else:
    601     new_axes = list(self.axes)
--> 603 res = self.apply("copy", deep=deep)
    605 res.axes = new_axes
    607 if self.ndim > 1:
    608     # Avoid needing to re-compute these

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:304, in BaseBlockManager.apply(self, f, align_keys, ignore_failures, **kwargs)
    302         applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    303     else:
--> 304         applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    305 except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
    306     if not ignore_failures:

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py:643, in Block.copy(self, deep)
    641 values = self.values
    642 if deep:
--> 643     values = values.copy()
    644 return type(self)(values, placement=self._mgr_locs, ndim=self.ndim)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\masked.py:680, in BaseMaskedArray.copy(self)
    678 def copy(self: BaseMaskedArrayT) -> BaseMaskedArrayT:
    679     data, mask = self._data, self._mask
--> 680     data = data.copy()
    681     mask = mask.copy()
    682     return type(self)(data, mask, copy=False)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 404. KiB for an array with shape (51724,) and data type float64
```

I suppose there is something very inefficient with my coding. Can anybody suggest what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I noticed something very weird about variable 'month'. I used

```
df_ufvdate['month'] = df_ufvdate['month'].astype('int64')
```

to convert 'month' into an integer and when I run df_ufvdate.info(max_cols=250, show_counts='True') I see that 'month' is type 'int64':

```
month                    51724 non-null  int64
```

However, when I run

```
df_ufvdate['month'].describe()
```

I get that 'month' is type 'float64':

```
count    51724.000000
mean         8.030895
std          3.693370
min          1.000000
25%          5.000000
50%          9.000000
75%         11.000000
max         12.000000
Name: month, dtype: float64
```

Here is more info on df_ufvdate:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 51724 entries, 1 to 62618
Data columns (total 211 columns)
dtypes: Int64(34), float64(105), int64(1), object(71)
memory usage: 85.3+ MB
```

Here is my desktop specs:

Windows 64,
RAM: 24GB,
Jupyter: 6.4.8,
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: Your `lambda` specifies `row` as the argument, but you don't use it.  Instead there's this unknown (to us) variable `month`.  Information on `df_ufvdate` might help.  Looking at the traceback, I don't think the `sin` calculation itself is causing the problem   It looks more like it's have problems writing the results back to the frame. 400KB doesn't look that big.  I wonder it there are things taking up most of the space, like the frame itself.  Adding a new column may require a full copy to a new frame.

Comment: I've edited my question to include more info about the dataframe and variable 'month'. Regarding not using 'row' as the argument, could you elaborate more about that? Please, let me know if there is any other information on the dataframe that would be helpful to add!

Comment: 1) `.describe()` returns a new series. *That* series has dtype float64.  2) You say `lambda row: get_sin(month, 12)`.  Why is `row` never used, and what is `month`?

Comment: Thank you all for the warning about not using 'row' as the argument, in the first version of my coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed:

```
def get_sin(row, column, max_value):
    value = row[column]
    sine =  np.sin(value * (2.*np.pi/max_value))
    return sine

def get_cosine(row, column, max_value):
    value = row[column]
    cosine = np.cos(value * (2.*np.pi/max_value))
    return cosine
```

and then these lambdas will do the trick:

```
df_ufvdate['month_sine'] = df_ufvdate.apply(lambda row: get_sin(row, 'month', 12), axis=1)

df_ufvdate['month_cosine'] = df_ufvdate.apply(lambda row: get_cosine(row, 'month', 12), axis=1)
```

Thank all who commented on this question!